# How to make the windowing system's focus switch to another application using elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to open the currently editing html page in a browser and then switch the
window system focus to the browser on a key press. I am using gnome desktop environment.

Below is the code (except the focus switching)

```
(defun open-in-browser()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  ; switch the windowing systems focus to the browser
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (browse-url (concat "file://" filename))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'open-in-browser)
```

I have tried using the **lower-frame** function and **suspend-frame** function,
both hides the emacs-frame which is not desired since i will not be able to see the code,
apart from that i have to type ALT-TAB **twice** to swith to emacs-frame again.

How to switch to another application (just like emulation of ALT-TAB in gnome) using
elisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is probably `unfocus-frame` but it is obsolete.  You need a cooperating window manager in order to actually do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are asking for. Changing the focus is the responsibility of the window manager and emacs cannot do it. You could

1. call an external program from emacs to do what you want
2. create a keybinding that would combine `<f5>` and `ALT-TAB`

Answer (score 0):

There are programs which can be used to control window managers from the command line, so that you can call a command from elisp to activate windows and stuff.

One such program is [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/). I don't know if it works with Gnome, you should try it.